# Firebase test lab showing unexpected test failures

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I've started using Firebase Test Lab recently with espresso. All the test cases pass on my local device but when it comes to testing devices present on google cloud, some test cases fail with exceptions like "NoMatchingViewException". I've tried increasing the wait time before the test runs and the fragment loads, but that too does not seem to help. Please help if you know how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried my app. The problem is that I used UDPSocket in my application.. kinda weird but there was this exception thrown : NoMatchingViewException.

So, I Mocked the UDP call. So at least I was able to do the UI automated test.